# Hive nested SUM over partition - error Expression not in GROUP BY key

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-query

I'm trying to get cumulative sum in one query. It works fine in SQL, PRESTO etc. but not in HIVE, which throws error msg.

```
create table test(store varchar(10), item int, quantity int)
insert into test
select 'depot',101,1
union select 'depot',101,2
union select 'depot',101,5
union select 'depot',102,1
union select 'depot',102,3
```

| store | item | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| depot | 101 | 1 |
| depot | 101 | 2 |
| depot | 101 | 5 |
| depot | 102 | 1 |
| depot | 102 | 3 |

```
select store, item,
sum(sum(revenue)) over (partition by store order by item)
from test
group by store, item
```

Expected output:

| store | item | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| depot | 101 | 8 |
| depot | 102 | 12 |

Error :

> [Code: 40000, SQL State: 42000]  Error while compiling statement:
> FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into
> Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check
> for circular dependencies. Underlying error:
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 1:24
> Expression not in GROUP BY key 'revenue'

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the queries:

```sql
select store, item, sum(sum_revenue) over (partition by store order by item) as revenue
from (
    select store, item, sum(revenue) as sum_revenue
    from test
    group by store, item
) as t
```